# Use generated image as pattern inside cairo graphics

Tags: graphics2d, cairo

I've gone through the cairo graphics examples using pattern.

```
pattern = cairo_pattern_create_for_surface (image);
cairo_pattern_set_extend (pattern, CAIRO_EXTEND_REPEAT);
```

Now instead of "image" I have a surface with a sequence of :-

```
cairo_move_to(cr, xc[0], yc[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < xc.size(); i++)
        cairo_line_to(cr, xc[i], yc[i]);
```

How do I use this generated cairo surface and use it as input for the pattern ?
It does not work if I simply use 
`pattern = cairo_pattern_create_for_surface (surface);`
where surface has the cairo_t cr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It does not work if I simply use pattern = cairo_pattern_create_for_surface (surface); where surface has the cairo_t cr.

Yes, it does.

The following code draws a cross to a 10x10 surface and then fill a 20x20 surface with this.

[image]

```
#include <cairo.h>

int main()
{
    cairo_surface_t *pattern_surface = cairo_image_surface_create(
            CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32, 10, 10);
    cairo_surface_t *result_surface = cairo_image_surface_create(
            CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32, 20, 20);
    cairo_t *cr;
    cairo_pattern_t *pattern;

    cr = cairo_create(pattern_surface);
    cairo_move_to(cr, 0, 0);
    cairo_line_to(cr, 10, 10);
    cairo_move_to(cr, 10, 0);
    cairo_line_to(cr, 0, 10);
    cairo_stroke(cr);
    cairo_destroy(cr);

    pattern = cairo_pattern_create_for_surface(pattern_surface);
    cairo_pattern_set_extend (pattern, CAIRO_EXTEND_REPEAT);

    cr = cairo_create(result_surface);
    cairo_set_source(cr, pattern);
    cairo_paint(cr);
    cairo_destroy(cr);

    cairo_surface_write_to_png(result_surface, "out.png");

    cairo_surface_destroy(pattern_surface);
    cairo_surface_destroy(result_surface);
    cairo_pattern_destroy(pattern);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Got it. My problem was that both surfaces were the same size..

`if (sg_surface2)

   cr = cairo_create(sg_surface2);

  cairo_scale(cr, 0.5, 0.5);

  cairo_set_source(cr, sg_pattern);

  cairo_paint(cr);`

Comment: Pattern_surface has to be smaller than result_surface. That was my mistake.